# my code is not passing two test cases on fcc

Tags: javascript

Basic Algorithm Scripting: Confirm the Ending
Check if a string (first argument, str) ends with the given target string (second argument, target).

This challenge can be solved with the .endsWith() method, which was introduced in ES2015. But for the purpose of this challenge, we would like you to use one of the JavaScript substring methods instead.

confirmEnding("Bastian", "n") should return true.
Passed
confirmEnding("Congratulation", "on") should return true.
Passed
confirmEnding("Connor", "n") should return false.
confirmEnding("Walking on water and developing software from a specification are easy if both are frozen", "specification") should return false.
Passed
confirmEnding("He has to give me a new name", "name") should return true.
Passed
confirmEnding("Open sesame", "same") should return true.
Passed
confirmEnding("Open sesame", "pen") should return false.
confirmEnding("Open sesame", "game") should return false.
Passed
confirmEnding("If you want to save our world, you must hurry. We dont know how much longer we can withstand the nothing", "mountain") should return false.
Passed
confirmEnding("Abstraction", "action") should return true.

i am unable to pass 4th and 8th cases with my current code.

```
function confirmEnding(str, target)
{
  // "Never give up and good luck will find you."
  // -- Falcor
  var first = str.length;
  let last  = target.length;
  for (var i = first-1; i>last-1; i--)
  {
    if(str[i]===target[last-1])
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

confirmEnding("Bastian", "n");
```

Answer (score 1):

just fun to do

```js
const Vals= 
[ { r:'Bastian',        t:'n' }
, { r:'Congratulation', t:'on' }
, { r:'Connor',         t:'n' }
, { r:'Walking on water and developing software from a specification are easy if both are frozen', t:'specification' }
, { r:'He has to give me a new name', t:'name' }
, { r:'Open sesame', t:'same' }
, { r:'Open sesame', t:'pen' }
, { r:'Open sesame', t:'game' }
, { r:'If you want to save our world, you must hurry. We dont know how much longer we can withstand the nothing', t:'mountain' }
, { r:'Abstraction', t:'action' }
]


function confirmEnding(strRef, target)
{
  let t = target.length
    , r = strRef.length
  while ( r>=0
       && t>=0
       && target.charAt(--t)==strRef.charAt(--r)
       ) {}
  return (t<0)
}


for (let test of Vals)
{
  console.log ( confirmEnding(test.r , test.t), ':', test.r , '==>' , test.t)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. It made things more intuitive to me.

```
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  let result = str.slice(-target.length);
  if (result === target) { 
    return true} else {
      return false}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code

```
if(str[i]===target[last-1])
{
  return true;
}
else
{
  return false;
}
```

you are either returning `true` or `false` at the first iteration (remember that `return` quits immediately the function) so you never get to check the second-last character.

Your code should instead return `true` only if all characters are matching (i.e. if the loop completes)